# Why am I getting SIGFPE here?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, variable-length-array

I have made sure that in the statement `i%a[i] == 0`, that `i` and `a[i]` are between 1 and 100. But still, I get this error message!

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m, x = 0, count = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    int a[n], b[m];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if(i % a[i] == 0)
        {
            x++;
        }
        else if(b[i] % i == 0)
        {
            x++;
        }

        if(x == 2)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        x = 0;
    }

    printf("%d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

**Error Message:**

```sh
Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
#0  0x0000000000401113 in main () at Solution.c:23
23                  if(i%a[i]==0){
```

Comment: Where did you make sure that `a[i]` is nonzero? Why are you starting counting from 0 in one place and from 1 in another? Why is your last loop up to 100 and not `n` and/or `m`?

Comment: You'll have to do something different when a[i] or b[i] equals 0.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including sample input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what the values of `i` and `a[i]` are.

Comment: `int main(void)`  It's not 1986.

Comment: You *must* *always* check the value returned by `scanf`.  `if( scanf("%d %d", &n, &m) == 2  && n > 0 && m > 0 ) ...`

Comment: @interjay its a constraint given in the problem statement

Comment: The problem statement has provided the following constraints: 1<a[i],b[i]<100

Answer (score 1):

Using the magic number `100` in this for loop

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
```

has a sense only in the case when `n` and `m` are not less than `101`.

Pay attention to that the program does not guarantee that `a[i]` is not equal to `0`.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/between-two-sets/problem Please refer to this question statement. There are clear constraints placed for the input values and there is nowhere a mention of a[i] being less than 1.

Comment: @YuvrajSakshith It does not matter what is written there. I said that your program does not guarantee this requirement. The user can enter any number.

Comment: The input is generated by the website is what I am saying. When such constraints are already placed, there is no question of dividing by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Vlad from Moscow correctly stated *that the program does not guarantee that `a[i]` is not equal to `0`.* But he didn't make clear to you that the problem you ask about is not that "*The user can enter any number*" for `a[i]` - the problem rather are the `a[i]` numbers which aren't entered at all. *The input is generated by the website*, and only `a[i]` for `i` from 0 to n−1 are defined, while your loop tries to access `a[i]` for `i` from 1 to 100; an undefined `a[i]` can be 0; when such an `a[i]` is 0, the operation `i` modulo `a[i]` gets you the `Arithmetic exception`.

So heed Vlad from Moscow's warning and change your program so that it does not attempt to use undefined values.

> is there a way I can fix this? Or an alternative approach?

You can basically keep your approach if you only use valid indexes into the arrays `a[]` and `b[]`; your main loop body could then be:

```
    {   x = 0;
        // use only valid indexes for a[] and b[]
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) if (i % a[j] == 0) ++x;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) if (b[j] % i == 0) ++x;
        if (x == n+m) ++count;
    }
```

Comment: Well, is there a way I can fix this? Or an alternative approach?

Comment: I expanded the answer.